# Whats wrong with this GOTO command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i've made this menu to select stuff but if i select start it crashes
i have no idea why. it must be an error in the code but this part is fairly new to me so i can't find the errors myself.
heres the code:

```
@echo off
title Tic Tac Toe
set "22=  "
set "23=  "
set "24=  "
set "32=  "
set "33=  "
set "34=  "
set "42=  "
set "43=  "
set "44=  "
set "pos1=22"


:Start
color f0
cls
echo                 ßßÛßß °ß° Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß 
echo                 °±Û°° ßÛß Û°°   °±Û°° ÛÜÜÛ Û°°   °±Û°° Û°°Û Ûßß 
echo                 °±Û°° ßßß ßßß   °±Û°° ß°°ß ßßß   °±Û°° ßßßß ßßß 
echo                                                        by SpoodyTheone

ping localhost -n 5 >nul

:menuSTART1
color 06
cls
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo ^|                ßßÛßß °ß° Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß          ^|
echo ^|                °±Û°° ßÛß Û°°   °±Û°° ÛÜÜÛ Û°°   °±Û°° Û°°Û Ûßß          ^|
echo ^|                °±Û°° ßßß ßßß   °±Û°° ß°°ß ßßß   °±Û°° ßßßß ßßß          ^|
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo                                PRESS E TO SELECT
echo                                    START^<
echo                                     HELP
echo                                     EXIT
:: Selection
choice /c:EWS >nul

if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto game
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto menuSTART3
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" goto menuSTART2

:menuSTART2
color 06
cls
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo ^|                ßßÛßß °ß° Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß          ^|
echo ^|                °±Û°° ßÛß Û°°   °±Û°° ÛÜÜÛ Û°°   °±Û°° Û°°Û Ûßß          ^|
echo ^|                °±Û°° ßßß ßßß   °±Û°° ß°°ß ßßß   °±Û°° ßßßß ßßß          ^|
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo                                PRESS E TO SELECT
echo                                    START
echo                                     HELP^<
echo                                     EXIT
:: Selection
choice /c:EWS >nul

if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto help
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto menuSTART1
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" goto menuSTART3

:menuSTART3
color 06
cls
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo ^|                ßßÛßß °ß° Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß   ßßÛßß ÛßßÛ Ûßß          ^|
echo ^|                °±Û°° ßÛß Û°°   °±Û°° ÛÜÜÛ Û°°   °±Û°° Û°°Û Ûßß          ^|
echo ^|                °±Û°° ßßß ßßß   °±Û°° ß°°ß ßßß   °±Û°° ßßßß ßßß          ^|
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo                                PRESS E TO SELECT
echo                                    START
echo                                     HELP
echo                                     EXIT^<
:: Selection
choice /c:EWS >nul

if "%errorlevel%"=="1" exit
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto menuSTART2
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" goto menuSTART1

:help
cls
echo.
echo         CONTROLS
echo -------------------------
echo ^|WASD to move the marker^|
echo ^|      E to place       ^|
echo -------------------------
echo.
echo         OBJECTIVE
echo -------------------------
echo ^| get 3 in a row to win ^|
echo -------------------------
pause >nul
goto menuSTART1

:game
if %rpos1% LSS 22 set "rpos1=42"
if %rpos1% GTR 44 set "rpos1=24"
set "rpos1=X "
cls
echo ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ
echo Û%42%Û  Û%43%Û  Û%44%Û
echo ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ
echo.
echo ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ
echo Û%32%Û  Û%33%Û  Û%34%Û
echo ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ
echo.
echo ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ
echo Û%22%Û  Û%23%Û  Û%24%Û
echo ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ  ÛÛÛÛ
choice /c:WASDE >nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto ad10
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto re1 
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" goto re10
if "%errorlevel%"=="4" goto ad1
if "%errorlevel%"=="5" goto sel

::add and subtract
:ad10
set /a "rpos1=+10"
goto game

:re1
set /a "rpos1=-1"
goto game

:re10
set /a "rpos=-10"
goto game

:ad1
set /a "rpos1=+1"
```

Comment: First, i see in :ad1, you don't goto game at the end, which will end the script when called

Comment: Please comment out or remove `@echo off` in order to see where the failure occurs. Saying "it crashes" does not give anyone here much of a clue. Please post error messages in the question.

Comment: Do not use numbers as the first character of your variable names.

Comment: the point of the variables being numbers is that +10 is 1 on the x axis and +1 is 1 on the y axis

Comment: Doesn't matter. Variables that start with numbers are reserved for script parameters. Just throw any letter in front of the variable name (or use a 2D array).

Comment: Please read this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line, under game:

```
if %rpos1% LSS 22 set "rpos1=42"
```

`rpos1` is initially undefined, and as you have no quotes it's evaluating against nothing.

Comment: that makes sense now that i think about it